# update of the null field

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table

```
create table control_answers
(
    first_id            uuid not null,
    second_id           uuid not null,
    control             integer,
    correct_answers     integer,
    constraint marker_skills_pk
        primary key (first_id, second_id)
);
```

`control` and `correct_answers` can be nulls.
I need to write two queries. The first increments two fields(`control, correct_answers`), the second only `control`.

`control` and `correct_answers` can be nulls. Because of this my queries doesn't work

```
UPDATE control_answers
SET (control, correct_answers) = (control + 1, correct_answers + 1)
WHERE first_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011' AND
    second_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011';
```

Comment: In MSSQL, If you add anything to NULL it will become NULL. Try to convert it to 0 by using ISNULL(Control,0) then update will happen.

Comment: In *all* SQL databases, any operation on a NULL produces a NULL. That's the SQL standard. `NULL` isn't 0, an empty string or missing value. It means the actual value is unknown. What result do you get when you add 1 to an unknown number? You can't know, ie NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected in all SQL databases. Any operation on a NULL produces a NULL. That's the SQL standard. `NULL` means `UNKNOWN`. It's not 0, an empty string or missing value. It means we have no idea what the value is. What result do you get when you add 1 to an unknown number? You can't know, ie `NULL`.

What if the field was named `temperatureInC` ? Not knowing doesn't mean the temperature is `0`. It would make no sense to get `1 C` by adding 1 to an unknown temperature

Use [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to replace NULL with an actual value, eg:

```
UPDATE control_answers
SET 
    control= COALESCE(control,0) + 1,
    correct_answers= COALESCE(correct_answers,0) + 1
WHERE first_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011' AND
    second_id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011';
```